# Converted dex2jar to .jar file. However results are empty in JD GUI

Tags: android, apk, dex2jar

I have converted my dex file from apk to to a jar file

Steps:

1. Change xyz.apk to xyz.zip

   Extract xyz.zip

   Copy classes.dex to my dex2jar folder

   Drag and release clases.dex onto dex2jar.abat

   Classes_dex2jar.jar is created

   Open clases_dex2jar.jar in JD Gui

   Empty screen for JD Gui

Can someone please advise what I have done wrong?

I have also tried doing step 4 using the terminal, but it yields the same result. I am running on Windows 7.

Comment: I have not experienced this. Are you sure that the apk and the generated files (dex and jar) are not corrupted?

Comment: At step 4 what did you write using terminal? Instead of command `dex2jar` did you try `d2j-dex2jar.bat` like `C:\Pathto-dex2jar-version\d2j-dex2jar.bat yourApk.apk` ?

Comment: everything you are right,go to command prompt and redirect the path to your folder(xyz),and then type "'dex3jar classes.dex'" after you can see this classes_dex2jar.jar file.Run classes_dex2jar.jar file in decompiler

Answer (score 1):

I have never renamed it to zip and extract the file. Normally I copy the apk file to the same folder with dex2jar folder and run:

```
  d2j-dex2jar.bat file.apk
```

It will generate the jar file: file.jar and you can open it normally in JD GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using cfr decompiler or procyon as they're much better than JD GUI and produce better results when combined with dex2jar.